# Web Installer in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

1. How can I configure my virtual directory to have Windows Integrated Security checked and Anonymous checked through installer.
2. How can I assign my newly created Virtual directory to an specied appPool which is already created on IIS6.0?

Any code snippets and how to perform these action thru maybe a Custom Actions Editor/ any web sites would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full answer to this, other than to take a look at [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which I've recently started looking at. The two links below give a starting point for some snippets of code for WiX

- [Windows Installer XML (WiX) 3.0 Snippets](http://blog.wharton.com.au/2007/06/windows-installer-xml-wix-30-snippets.html)
- [Creating a Virtual Directory with WiX works a treat](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2004/10/08/179.aspx)

The Setup/Installer projects in VS2k8 aren't particularly extensible (at least that I've found!) so changing to something like WiX is probably your best bet. A bit of a step learning curve, but hopefully what you're after.